# Karate Parallel fail since 1.3.0

Tags: karate

Good morning,

I just mounted the version of Karate and I have an unexpected behavior on the execution of tests in parallel.

I have a single feature file that I execute in parallel. In 10 simple API scenarios.
If I add a sleep of 10 seconds in two scenarios then the execution will take 27 seconds.
In 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 it takes 17 seconds. As if the parallelization had no place.

I use the sleep method proposed on the documentation. My sleep method is called in CallSingle in my background file ( like in the Example below  )

Result :

```
Karate version: 1.1.0
======================================================
elapsed:  16,70 | threads:   25 | thread time: 87,05 
features:     1 | skipped:    0 | efficiency: 0,21
scenarios:   34 | passed:    34 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

```
Karate version: 1.3.0
======================================================
elapsed:  25,51 | threads:   25 | thread time: 126,30 
features:     1 | skipped:    0 | efficiency: 0,20
scenarios:   34 | passed:    34 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

My runner :

```
Results results = Runner.path(
"classpath:Tenant/TenantAPI/gestionTenantAPI.feature"
).tags("\~@ignore").reportDir("target/surefire-reports-myrunner).outputCucumberJson(true).outputJunitXml(true)
.parallel(25);

        karateReportCucumber.generateReport(results.getReportDir(), runner);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
```

Exemple of Feature :

```
Feature : Test Sleep

Background:

    * def SleepGenerator = karate.call('classpath:Common/Utils/generators.feature@sleepGenerator').SleepGenerator

Scenario: Number 01

    * def pause = SleepGenerator(10000)
    
    Given url  url_api + '/v1/myapp/code/karate'
    And  header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And  header Authorization = "Bearer " + token_bearer
    When method GET
    Then status 200

Scenario:Number 01

    * def pause = SleepGenerator(10000)
    
    Given url  url_api + '/v1/myapp/code/MAGICSTRING'
    And  header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And  header Authorization = "Bearer " + token_bearer
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please read this thread: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2222#issuecomment-1420534265

In the meantime, if you can try build locally that will greatly help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick response.
I just got the Karate sources, I built a 1.4.0-Snapshot from the development branch and I have exactly the same result.

```
Karate version: 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
======================================================
elapsed:  24,24 | threads:   25 | thread time: 165,23 
features:     1 | skipped:    0 | efficiency: 0,27
scenarios:   34 | passed:    34 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

You can contact me later on my Stack account if you want a beta tester. Am using karate since 4 Year.

Comment: hi - yes or can you comment on the issue I linked and we can discuss there. in the meantime can you try the suggestion of NOT using a JS function for a sleep (see the start of that thread) and just use a Java thread.sleep() - because of the reasons given in that thread, we may have to enforce that restriction - which is that you can't use JS functions that block. if you need to block, use Java